# Twitterizer 2 and C# - Namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-directives, twitterizer, assembly-references

I have a silly problem with Twitterizer2 and probably me :) . I add the reference twitterizer 2.3.1 from my downloads directory along with the newtonsoft one by right clicking on references and browsing to find them.

I then add

```
using Twitterizer;
```

lo and behold all my squiggly red underlines go away

on all this sort of code:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
```

when I go to run it(with debug), I get an error:

> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Twitterizer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now 
     using Twitterizer;

becomes in error(red and squiggly). It is like it has been dereferenced. I add it back and all is well until I run it - arggh

TIA

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using VS2010? If so, try to go project properties -> Application Tab and make sure that you are not using a Framework version that has "client profile" in it.

Comment: You sir, are a genius :) I have no idea how I would have found that out. Thank you. Now I shall have to read up on what the hell that means.

Comment: @user510662, thank you. It took me a while to figure out myself, the first time I had a similar problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS2010 vb.net you need to go to project properties ->Publish Tab-> Prerequisites

Uncheck ms .net framework 4 client profile, and check ms .net framework 4

Comment: Also change it in the compile tab using these instructions:http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/12/29/how-to-change-the-target-framework-version-for-a-visual-basic-project.aspx