# How use NuGet packages and namespaces with f#

Tags: .net, f#, assemblies, nuget

I've a little problem, I'm trying use twitterizer with a f# app..this is the first time than I use NuGet, I install it and download twitterizer from NuGet Repo, It appear inside my references, so far so good, but now, when I try use it I get:

The namespace or module Twitterizer is not defined

I'm using

```
open Twitterizer (actually the intellisense detect twitterizer good)
```

in c# would be:

```cs
using Twitterizer;
```

I was reading a similar question:
[F# defining/using a type/module in another file in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172888/f-defining-and-using-a-namespace-in-the-same-project)

but in my case is a reference and not a file..I know than it is a very noob question but I can't see the mistake

Comment: Are you compiling or using F# Interactive?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you use it (`open Twitterizer`) in `.fs` file. Are you sure that Twitterizer assembly is still in references in project where you try to use it?
2. If you use it in a script file (`.fsx`). Are you sure that you specify path in `#r` correctly with full path to Twitterizer assembly?

Actually referencing assemblies via NuGet or not doesn't affect the way you reference them. NuGet can initialy add reference to needed assembly (Twitterizer in your case), but it won't keep that reference forever if you decide to delete the reference. Additionaly, when you install assembly via NuGet it could add reference to one of you project, and then you try to use this assembly in another project where reference to Twitterizer assembly wasn't specified.

So techicaly NuGet just downloads (if needed) assembly you need with its dependencies and initialy adds reference to it into one of you project, that's all. Then you can work with this assembly as if you downloaded it yourself.

So, check references in all projects from which you try to use Twitterizer.

Comment: Hi..I notice than you are the twitterizer author..well I can resolve the problem reading the response from Klaus Byskov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203674/twitterizer-2-and-c-sharp-namespace-could-not-be-found  I think maybe you must add this info in the twitterizer page..maybe exist other noobs like me than it could be usefull :D ...thanks for response my question and for the twitterizer lib ...

Comment: @CocoOS no, I'm not a twitterizer author, actually I'm not even aware of it and what is it. Sorry :)